# How to annotate jersey method if I want to pass json?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, form-parameter

I have following jersey method declaration:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/fooPath")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response isSellableOnline(@FormParam("productCodes") final List<String> productCodes,
                                     @FormParam("storeName") final String storeName,
                                     @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
```

In rest client I try to invoke following method like this:
[image]

When I debug method I see that received parameters are null:

[image]

How to rewrite method declaration?

Comment: There has to be something in the server logs. Post that too.

Comment: You are right. Now I will rephrase question.

Comment: @Gimby topic updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because on the isSellableOnlie method you are expecting or trying to extract form parameters, but the incoming POST request is JSON.

Well if you want JSON you should make POJO Class to be able to serialize the JSON.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Store {

private String storeName;
private List<String> productCodes;

public Store() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public List<String> getProductCodes() {
    return productCodes;
}
}
```

And then in your method:

```
@POST
@Path("/fooPath")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response isSellableOnline(Store store) {
   store.getName();
...
}
```

Comment: How to rewrite my method?